# Is it possible for Unity to build directly to Arduino?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino

I am working on a project for a client and the request came in to bypass the arduino ide altogether and just write all the code in c# and have Unity build directly to the board.  Is this something that would even be possible?

I know there are plenty of libraries I can access to communicate with the serial devices directly, could I just do this?

Has anyone tried to do this before?

Comment: you are trying to have a game interface with an arduino? Yes, you can communicate over serial port with the arduino from C#, but the code *running on the arduino* needs to be written in C and compiled for arduino with the arduino libraries.

Comment: Ok thank you, I assumed it wasn't going to be directly possible with straight c# and Unity.  They wanted to be able to build directly from Unity to the arduino.

Comment: you can call command-line programs to compile for arduino and upload to the board in C#, but the code you're compiling has to be in C(++)

Comment: _"Unity build directly to the board"_ - [Unity does not support Arduino](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206336795-What-platforms-are-supported-by-Unity-).